# Compute the probability density function of $X_k$

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

**The question**

The number of calls $N_t$ - entering the hub by the hour t  is distribute $Pois\left(\lambda t\right)$.

We will mark $X_k$ the time of arrival of the k-call.

Calculate the probability density function of each $K\geq1$.

**My attempt**
I tried to solve it with the formula:
$P_{X_{k}}\left(x\right)=\sum_{a=0}^{\infty}f_{X_{k}|N_{t}=a}\left(x\right)\cdot P_{N_{t}}\left(a\right)$

but I really don't know how.

Thanks